# Ok to let cat watch videos of birds?

Tags: cats, behavior, hunting

My cat loves chirping at birds. Moved recently to where there's fewer birds to chirp at through window. He seems to like (or at least be entertained by) watching videos of birds on my computer. Is this ok? My concern is that it might confuse him when he can't touch them, or when goes behind the computer to see where they've flown off to. Is this sort of thing somehow harmful? Or is ok for him to enjoy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is okay to provide this form of entertainment for your cats.

I've actually seen this as a permanent feature in a few vet clinics in my area, with an elevated shelf to put the pet carrier and a screen in front showing videos of birds and mice.

---

Not all cats react the same way, so you might want to supervise them for a while, e.g. to prevent damage to modern LCD screens when the cat tries to claw at the image. As mentioned in comments, you might want to look into aftermarket screen protectors to prevent such damage when you're not around to intervene.

Other precautions might include making sure the display is firmly attached to the wall, or has a stand that will tolerate the cat jumping on top of the screen without falling over, in order to prevent potential hazards.

Comment: There's screen protectors for TVs amusingly enough, and this feels like the one case where it makes sense